# Techniques for persistent website data storage with a low or zero server-side back-end overhead & setup?

Tags: json

I'm looking to build a dynamic website without bringing much extra server-side code/apps into the picture, and need some persistent & dynamic information that would be stored, displayed, edited, & displayed across page loads.  I'd like to try some alternatives to using a full-fledged php+database back-end, a database is ideal, but I'd only be using the php for a single script for storing json data, and expect that running the full-fledged php apache mod for that purpose is overkill.

So for example, I want to have:
 an html page
--> that loads some message data via javascript (e.g. "Killroy was here.")
--> Which can be edited by an admin, via js ( "roy was here" )
--> The page can be left, and returned to with a different browser, by a public user
--> and the message would repopulate to the changed state ("roy was here")

Ideally the json data would be stored either on a free external service (amazon ec2 or something?  google app engine? I have no idea what might be available for this purpose), or the app & database for storing the data server side would be simple and have quick setup.

So what ways are there to acheive those goals?

Comment: So what's wrong with a usual PHP installation?

Comment: I'm trying to broaden my horizons and see how possible it is to work in js primarily instead of relying on a server-side assist, these days...

Comment: You definitely can now, for example Firebase's Realtime Database gives you direct access from client side JavaScript: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), maybe that's what you're looking for. In short words it's an event driven I/O framework using JavaScript on the server.

Addition:
[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is a document-oriented database with a RESTful JSON API that can be accessed by simple HTTP-requests. That sounds a bit like what you are seeking, but still has server side implementation.

Comment: A little more setup than I was hoping for though, I'm really only looking for some data storage, like by key, or something.

Comment: But you any sort of server side logic. A persistence layer is not enough, there has to be a program running on the server, that writes or reads. Browser javascript is strictly client side.

Comment: right, was looking for just such software, software that has simplified writes & reads built in to allow for storing of data.  's alright, it's something I'll pursue eventually.